# exception handling with different error codes

Tags: python, exception, mkdir

I'd like to know how to handle different exceptions that have the same "type". I'm trying to use some code to make a directory:

```
os.mkdir(target_dir_name)
```

And I know this can fail for a variety of reasons, for example if the directory already exists:

```
OSError: [Errno 17] File exists:
```

or if there's no permissions to create a new dir:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
```

I'd like to tailor my error messages to the specific failure cause, so I came up with the following code:

```
try:
  os.mkdir(target_dir_name)
except OSError as e:
  if e.errno == 17:
    print "Warning: Directory %s already exists, executing a rebuild" % (target_dir_name)
  elif e.errno == 13:
    sys.exit("Error: Directory "+target_dir_name+" cannot be created incorrect permissions")
```

but I'd like to do something a little less hardcoded. Is there a Pythonic way I could update my sub-failure checks?

Comment: In Python 3.3, there errors got split into distinct types: http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-3151-reworking-the-os-and-io-exception-hierarchy

Comment: I haven't found an elegant solution yet since a lot of those exception and error types are so specific with their attributes. So generally in this case I usually do what http://stackoverflow.com/a/16268642/158111 suggests - wrap specific error handling into a function and avoid repetitive hardcoding.

Comment: @delnan - Thanks for the input. This will be a distributed script when I'm done with it and I'm trying not to tie myself down to one version of Python if I can help it. I can't guarantee what everyone will be running, but I figured 2.7.3 would be pretty safe (as that comes standard on the latest stable Ubuntu release)

Comment: 2.7.3 is almost as version-locked as you can get. The 2.7 line is the final version of Python 2. Python 2.7.4 and 2.7.5 are bugfix releases, and Python 3 breaks backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

The only information I've found... which I guess is my best answer:

With the [errno module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/errno.html#module-errno) I can at least rewrite my current code as:

```
import errno
#...
except OSError as e:
  if e.errno == errno.EEXIST:
    print "Warning: Directory %s already exists, e..."
  elif e.errno == errno.EACCESS:
    sys.exit("Error: Directory "+target_dir_name+"..."
```

If I upgrade to [python 3.2](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-3151-reworking-the-os-and-io-exception-hierarchy) there is the much nicer:

```
except FileExistsError:
  print ("Warning: Directory %s already exists, e...")
except PermissionError:
  sys.exit("Error: Directory "+target_dir_name+"...")
```

Seems I could do something fancy with using `sys.version_info.major` and `minor` to make sure it's at least `3.2` as well.

Hopefully something better will come up...